# Does the word 'green board' exist?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology

A friend of mine said he bought a green board for his house. However, when he used the word *green board*, I realized that I never used that word before. Normally, I would call it *chalkboard* for either a green or black board. Occasionally, I might use the word *black board*.

Basically, my question is: does the word *green board* actually exist?

I included a picture in case someone does not know what I am talking about. I am aware that I can use the word *green board* to mean a surfboard painted green. There are other examples but hopefully I am making some sense.

He showed me the board; it looked like the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your friend likely bought **[greenboard](http://www.dictionaryofconstruction.com/definition/green-board.html)**, which is moisture-resistant gypsum board or wallboard, distinguishable by its green facing paper.

Addendum:  Are you sure what he showed you didn't look like this:
[image]

Comment: He showed me the board, it looked like the picture above. I should have been more specific, sorry.

Comment: @mika Indeed;sorry, I  should have read more closely.  The term *greenboard* certainly exists, and when somebody says, "I got some greenboard for my house," they are almost surely talking about the construction material and not something to write on with chalk.  Apparently, not your friend, though.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes.

Merriam-Webster defines a [greenboard](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greenboard) as:

> a chalkboard with a green surface

Dictionary.com [defines it as](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/greenboard):

> a green chalkboard or blackboard.

Comment: General reference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ??

Comment: Answers to general reference questions.
From Meta: "...  'trivial' questions that can be adequately answered with LMGTFY or another simple link" –  FumbleFingers  //  "If we accept the axiom that trivial questions are bad for the site, then the proper response to a general reference question is: 1.Don't answer! 2… [Vote] to close. The point is not to encourage trivial questions. If you post an answer or vote up an existing answer, you're implicitly encouraging more questions like it.’"–Martha

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks; I'm quite new here and not familiar with all the rules. Is there an accepted definition of "general reference"?

Comment: I checked; Googling 'greenboard meaning' or  'green board meaning' gave the M-W link top of the list. Have you read the *advice at the _help center_ and looked at the set close-vote reasons? *'Where can I find answers to simple and basic questions?

If your question is simple and can probably be easily answered by looking it up, then you may find common online internet resources to be of some help. View our list of community recommended resources to find some that may be of help to you.

Try a dictionary if you want to know what a word or phrase means, how it evolved, or how it is pronounced.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth all very valid points but perhaps best reserved towards the more experienced members of the community, who are *guilty* of helping users solve simple "general reference" question thanks to copy&paste. Anyway, rand al'thor, now you know what the initial cryptic comment was about!

Comment: @Mari-Lou A 'The more experienced members of the community' being those who've read 'New to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange? Find out everything you need to get started by taking the tour.' at the Help Center?